# CodeIgniter Admin template system

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I want to allow the Administrator to change the Admin Dashboard Layout by itself and add an option to so they can upload their own layouts or "Premium" layouts.

However, I don't have logic to do that. I tought in one thing:

- Based CSS (user can create new template using CSS with the same names);

This seems strange.

How do I change back-end code dynamically? There are many views with a lot of PHP code. I know many CMSs that allow users to change the front end (instead of the Admin Dashboard). I want similar functionality for my Admin Dashboard. This is for an MMORPG game, and `admin/user` panel is in the same "page". Maybe some Administrators will not like having a panel that is the same as another server.

Comment: Your question is both hard to understand, and likely to be closed because it is very broad. S.O. caters specifically to code-based questions: can you show us what you've tried to do to implement this and where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store template name in database and define it on `MY_Controller.php` file under `application/core` folder.

For example;

MY_Controller.php file:

```
<?php

Class Front_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> model('CommonModel');
        $this -> activeTemplate = $this -> CommonModel -> activeTemplate();
    }
}
```

CommonModel.php file:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class CommonModel Extends CI_Model
{
    function activeTemplate()
    {
        return $this -> db -> get_where('settings', array('feature' => 'frontTemplate'))->row('value');
    }
```

And finally, our Controller sample:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Home Extends Front_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this -> load -> view($this -> activeTemplate.'/front/master', $data);
    }
```

So, if you want to use that structure you need to open new folders under your view folder with theme names which are stored in our database. For example; if `$this -> activeTemplate` returns "theme1" value, you need to add your views under `application/views/theme1/front`(or something else).

If you use that structure, you can change your front side's theme easily.

Comment: Oh! That's good, thanks for u reply! But I still in doubt with PHP codes.

Comment: What kind of doubts?